# Property of matrix invertability

Tags: linear-algebra

Now an inverse intuitively means as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

How I've understood is that it is a matrix that it transforms a vector transformed by A back to it's original position, if A is the standard transformation matrix then,

There are two questions that come to me:

1) Why should A be row equivalent to the Identity matrix I? (Even more confusing is that it's product with it's inverse should be I), where's the intuition?
2) Is being row equivalent a sufficient condition or a necessary condition or the one and only condition? (I don't see this stated much anywhere)

Comment: do you know about determinants? If so I can place an answer with that in mind.

Comment: @realestate ,  Not the intuition, I do know that they determine the change in area during a linear transformation though. However, It'd be nice if you didn't introduce mathematical notations, just mere reasoning, intuition and geometry, (if possible please :) )

Comment: You’ll probably need to use multiple sets of coordinate axes in order to visualize row-equivalence.

Comment: @amd , I'd like to know how?

Comment: Row operations are essentially a change of basis for the domain. Look up “row picture” and “column picture” of a system of linear equations.